# I want to find the value who exist in array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 queries and I would like to know the elements (date_debut) of the second query which exists in the first query (dateincal). The elements of the second query can appear one or more times in the first query.
once the dates (date debut) (dateincal) have been found i want to be able to then retrieve also the other information for the element found

```
        $feries = Jourferie::Select('dateincal', 'description')
                    ->where('dateincal', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
                    ->where('dateincal', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth())
                    ->get();

    $plannings = Planning::Select('date_debut', 'id', 'agent_id', 'site_id')
                 ->where('id', '!=', 0)
                 ->where('statut', 'provisoire')
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that way can help you:

```
foreach($feries as $ferie){

$myresult = $plannings->contains('date_debut',$ferie->dateincal) 
/* do things */

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but the result is not what I expected, it returns me true when I want to have the existing values